# Adding a functional Scrollbar to a ListView for users who don't like touch scrolling

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, scrollbar

I have a requirement to add a scroll bar that is always visible and which can be directly used by mouse or touch to scroll the contents of a large ListView.

The normal way of scrolling on mobile devices is by swiping up or down.  During the scroll process there will be a small scrollbar visible but that scrollbar disappears and even while visible it can't be used to do any actual scrolling.

After much searching I could not find what I needed.

So my question is:  Is there a way to make the scrollbar in the ListView fully usable or should I disable it and create a separate scrollbar which I will need to keep in sync.   If so how?

For a functional example of something I would be working with see: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/124j

Comment: You can achieve this by migrating to extjs 6 modern toolkit. It has normal scrollbars if you display on PC, and touch scroll in mobile devices. 90% of the code is same as sencha touch 2.4

Comment: @abeyaz, thanks for the comment.  That does not quite fit our needs but it might help someone else.  I am specifically working with a Sencha Touch app compiled via Cordova for a Windows Tablet.